# Laravel check if first() returned anything

Tags: laravel

I wonder that the proper way to handle if first() didnt return anything is?

Right now I use this:

```
$user = User::where('role_id', $role)->first(['role_id']);

        if (is_null($user)) {
            //Not found, handle some stuff
        } else {
            $user->DoSomeUpdatesOnThatUser();
        }
```

This seems to work. I know there is a `firstOrFail()` but I use this function inside a job so I dont need to return a 404 page just handle it doesnt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isNotEmpty` method for this situation:

```
$user = User::where('role_id', $role)->get();// get the collection
if ($user->isNotEmpty()) {// checking if it is empty or not
    $user->first()->DoSomeUpdatesOnThatUser();
}
```

But anyway, I don't think it's much more cleaner than your way.

Answer (score 0):

You mention `firstOrFail()`, but that's not limited to showing 404 pages. All it does is throw a `ModelNotFoundException`, which you can catch manually instead of letting it be handled elsewhere.

For instance:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

try {
    $user = User::where('role_id', $role)->first(['role_id']);
    $user->doTheFunkyStuff();
catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    myAmazingFailureFunction();
}
```

Edit: That said, I don't think there's anything wrong with your approach either. :)